# How to get an Excel graph show "up to" current day of week

Tags: excel

In Mac Excel 2011 I have a Scrum burndown chart that tracks the number of points ‘burnt’ per day (starting from say 100, hopefully burning down to 0).
The number of points per day is made up of a sum of X number of columns (tasks).
I then have a marked line graph which takes it’s Y value data from the summed points per day.

My issue is that the marked line graph will always display 5 work days worth of burn, even though we might be on Tuesday.

I need a solution that means I don’t have to manually update the graph y value each day (adding it), instead the graph knows it is Wednesday, and selects data up to Wednesday.

Comment: Are you trying to show the last five days?

Comment: @Pynner I wanted the graph to 'grow' from 1 day to a max of 5 days depending on the day of week, without having to edit the formula all the time. The na() function suggested below solved the problem. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to show the days for the whole week? (probably, since a 1 or 2 day chart early in the week will look funny.) Are the Y values linked from another cell?

If so, change your links from

```
=A1
```

to

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=0,NA(),A1)
```

NA() produces #N/A in the cell, which isn't plotted.